# Selenium - best way to write error checking in java?

Tags: java, selenium

I'm VERY new to java\Selenium. What I am trying to achive is test whether our website comes back up after patching, what needs to happen is

1 - open chrome
2 - open url
3 - log in
4 - download pdf

Im trying to catch an error every time my bot hits a roadblock. At the moment i have the below code

What is the best way to write into the code when a bad password prompt pops up on the website

Thanks and sorry if this is such an easy issue

```
package webdriver;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

public class launchbrowser {

    public static WebDriver driver = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        File file1 = new File("out.txt");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file1);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);


        try {
        //Adds driver ver - dont remove
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",".\\drivers\\chromedriver78.exe" );
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }
        //Catch the Error
        catch (Exception e){
            pw.println("unable to launch browser");
        }



        try {       
        //open webpage and maximizes the window
        driver.navigate().to("****Webpage****");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
            }
        //Catch the Error
        catch (Exception e){
            pw.println("Unable to open Webpage");
        }



        try {
        //locate Member Number\email
        WebElement Username=driver.findElement(By.id("Login.Member number or email"));
        Username.sendKeys("****test username****");
        }
        //Catch the Error
        catch (Exception e){
            pw.println("Unable to enter username");
        }

        try {
        //locate password 
        WebElement Password=driver.findElement(By.id("Login.Password"));
        Password.sendKeys("****test password****");
        }
        //Catch the Error
        catch (Exception e){
            pw.println("Unable to enter password");
        }


        //Click Login
        WebElement Enter=driver.findElement(By.id("Login.Password"));
        Enter.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);


        try {
        //Download a statement
        WebElement Transactions=driver.findElement(By.id("TransactionSummary"));
        Transactions.click();

        WebElement PDF=driver.findElement(By.linkText("Go"));
        PDF.click();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            pw.println("Unable to download statement");
        }

        pw.close();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to achieve, depending on what you want to test:

1. Find your pop up element using explicit wait, if it doesn't show up, your explicit wait will throw an exception, which means your password might be valid.
2. Determine your password is valid or not, then you will decide whether you need to find pop up element.

In the 1st option, I assumed that your validation had worked perfectly. And the 2nd one is checking that your validation worked properly.